# Rails 5: image and loop of images are not showing in email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have this in the mailer:

```
attachments.inline["logo.png"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo.png")
```

And in the email template I have this:

```
<%= image_tag attachments['logo.png'].url %>
```

It works just fine and the logo does appear in the email.

Now this is the weird part, I have another image that is not in the asset pipeline but stored in the database and also a loop of other images stored in the database. And none of them appear in the email. The email goes through without any errors. Any idea what might be wrong and how I can debug this?

```
<%= image_tag @account.image.thumb.url %>
   <% @attachments.each do |attachment| %>
     <%= image_tag attachment.images.thumb.url %>
<% end %>
```

I'm using the `gem carrierwave` to attach image and I uploading this version:

```
version :thumb do
  process resize_to_fill: [1024, 768]
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options here: either your images, stored in the databases, also have a public-facing url, and then you can use those. But most likely they do not, and then you have to add the images as `attachments` to your email as well, and then use the `attachments` when building the email.

So in your mailer write something like:

```
@attachments.each do |attachment|
  attachments.inline[attachment.image.original_filename] = attachment.image.thumb.read
end
```

and then in your mail view, you can just iterate over all `@attachments` again, and use the correct `attachments.inline[...]`, something like

```
<% @attachments.each do |attachment| %>
  <%= image_tag attachments.inline[attachment.image.original_filename].url %>
<% end %>
```

Note: I am not entirely sure of the correct syntax here (you use `images` but I presume it should be singular? also you should check what is the best unique way for your image, maybe the `original_filename` is not ideal, you could also just use the `id` of the `attachment`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @nathanvda. Something really weird just happened! Two days ego the images were not showing in an email. Today, before adding your code I tied one more email and saw that the images where going through. I'm using safari for mac, so I even tried chrome for mac and the first email the images did not appear. But after that all the emails that I've sent contained the images correctly. I even restarted the server and cleared the browser history and it still worked. Now why would that even happen???

Comment: It sounds to me like you are probably accessing an image with a signed url that is expiring before you are able to open the email. You'll experience the problem again if that's the case.

Comment: Is this in development or in production? If you are testing in development (sorry if this is too obvious) it will only work on your machine with a url like `localhost:3000`, and it will only work if your dev server is running, and so it will not work if you forward this mail to anybody on another machine. In production it should work, but there it still could be the case someone can manipulate the `@attachments` in between sending the email and someone reading it. So inlining provides a working standalone snapshot and that may or may not be more suitable.

Comment: @nathanvda, yes this is in development and I'm only trying to view the email content while the server is running and only on my machine. So if I do add this in the mailer `@attachments.each do |attachment|
  attachments.inline[attachment.image.file.filename] = attachment.image.thumb.read
end` then how can iterate over all @attachments in my mail view?

Comment: I am sorry, I believed that was obvious. Since you build a list of inline attachments, addressable by a name, you just acces that list again. The only problem is finding a unique name, but you can for instance just use the attachment id's as well (as all mentioned). I edited my answer to show more code. Hope it is more clearer now.